# Ember.js call function after template is rendered

Tags: ember.js

I am building an app using Ember.js that will display a map. In order to display the map, I need to call some JS after the rendering of the map div.

structure layout:

```
- app/router.js
--> this.route('map')
- app/controllers/map.js
--> build function
- app/templates/map.hbs
--> <div id="map"/>
```

In jquery I would use the document ready to launch my JS code:

> $( handler )

I think I should use a View and a callback like ".on('didInsertElement')" but I can't get the plumbing to work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I add a coffee and the answer came.

You need to link a view to your template. here is the new structure layout:

- app/router.js

  - this.route('map')
- app/controllers/map.js
- app/templates/map.hbs

  - {{view id="map"}}
- app/views/map.js

  - build function(){}.on('didInsertElement')

Actualy, the control of the template rendering is done in the View layer and not the controler. The controler as I understand is aimed for user interactions.